# How to test a module in NestJs

Tags: nestjs

I'm adding tests on a project and improving coverage. I would like to know how can I test a module definition (mymodule.module.ts file) in NestJs. 
In particular, I'm testing a main module that imports other modules, one of them inits a db connection, this means that I need to mock the service on the other module, to avoid a real db connection.
At this moment I have something like this:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const instance: express.Application = express();

    module = await NestFactory.create(MyModule, instance);
});
describe('module bootstrap', () => {
    it('should initialize entities successfully', async () => {
        controller = module.get(MyController);
        ...

        expect(controller instanceof MyController).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

This works, but I'm sure this can get improvements :)

The ideal thing would be something like overrideComponent method provided by Test.createTestingModule.

P.S: I'm using 4.5.2 version

Answer (score 9):

Improved my tests based on @laurent-thiebault answer:

```js
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { ThingsModule } from './things.module';
import { ThingsResolver } from './things.resolver';
import { ThingsService } from './things.service';

describe('ThingsModule', () => {
  it('should compile the module', async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [ThingsModule],
    }).compile();

    expect(module).toBeDefined();
    expect(module.get(ThingsResolver)).toBeInstanceOf(ThingsResolver);
    expect(module.get(ThingsService)).toBeInstanceOf(ThingsService);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can now test your module (at least for code coverage) by building it that way:

```js
describe('MyController', () => {
    let myController: MyController;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
           imports: [MyModule],
        }).compile();

        myController = module.get<MyController>(MyController);
    });

    it('should the correct value', () => {
        expect(myController.<...>).toEqual(<...>);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

We usually didn't test `.module.ts` files directly.

---

we do this in `e2e` testing.

but I wonder `why one should test the the module !` and you are trying to test if the module can initialize it's components , it should.

but i recommend you do this in `e2e` testing.
in my opinion, in unit testing you should focus on testing the services or other components behaviors not the modules.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to test if a module can initialize all its dependencies successfully. Improving coverage would be a collateral benefit. Something like this https://medium.com/spektrakel-blog/angular-testing-snippets-ngmodule-providers-b8e9559587e7 but in NestJs version.

Comment: The other reason is to show coverage on code coverage report, if we don't test it it's red

Comment: @Reza
Adding this to package.json 
`jest: {"collectCoverageFrom": ["**/*.{!(module),}.(t|j)s"]}`
fixes the problem with "red" coverage.